# Where is my money

Tags: wallet

I am a newbie, pretty good on the computer. I received a email from coinbase that they have my deposit.
Where does it go.
Is there a easy step by step to find my funds, I want to buy something today.

Comment: So you spent real money in exchange for Bitcoins, gave it under management of a company Coinbase, and don't know what to do with it next. And instead of reading Coinbase's help resources (before sending them money), you ask us... Strange!

Comment: You got an email from Coinbase... did you already have an established customer relationship with them in any way? There are tons of scams going around where spammers send email "from coinbase" saying "we have your money", but there's actually nothing of the sort and they just want to scam you in some way.

Comment: Are you saying you signed up for an account at coinbase.com and deposited funds to purchase bitcoins? This seems like a reasonable assumption, but it pays to be sure!

Answer (score 0):

It goes to your coinbase account. Just login to www.coinbase.com and click my account and you will see your funds.

Answer (score 0):

Your deposit to coinbase will be credited to your "USD wallet" on your coinbase account when it clears. The USD wallet is where your USD is stored until you spend it, but you cant spend it until the bank transaction has cleared and coinbase knows that it's irreversable. This usually takes 1-2 weeks.

After the bank has cleared the transaction, coinbase will credit your USD wallet and you will be able to buy cryptos.